# How to access Google Pub/Sub Custom Attributes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jinja2, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a set of Cloud Functions that send Pub/Sub messages to other functions in my pipeline. One of these functions is an email function. Ideally, I'd like to use Jinja2 templates in this email function that get filled in based on the custom attributes of my Pub/Sub messages. My code that sends the message is as follows:

```
def publish_detailed_message(project: str,
                             topic: str,
                             message: str,
                             **kwargs):
    """publish_message posts a message to a PubSub topic.

    Args:
        project (str): the project that the topic is located
        topic (str): the topic to publish the message
        message (str): the message to be sent
    """
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(
        publisher_options=pubsub_v1.types.PublisherOptions(
            enable_message_ordering=True,
        )
    )
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project, topic)

    attributes = {}
    data_str = f"{message}"
    data = data_str.encode('utf-8')
    if kwargs:
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            attributes[str(k)] = str(v)
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, **attributes)
    else:
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    print(future.result())
    print(f"Published messages to {topic_path}")
```

I've been able to successfully access these attributes when including the following in my def main():

```
        ATTR = {'Team': 'Arch', 'Data': 'Production'}
        publish_message(PROJECT,
                        TOPIC,
                        MESSAGE,
                        **ATTR)
```

This has allowed me to print the attributes, as well as recognize them in the Pub/Sub message itself. What I'd like to do is grab these attributes with my email function that is triggered by the Pub/Sub message and then pass these attributes into my Jinja2 template. I have successfully been able to log the attributes with the following generic cloud function.

```
    """The entrypoint for the work."""
    name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print(
        """This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {} to {}
    """.format(
            context.event_id, context.timestamp, context.resource["name"]
        )
    )
 
    logger.info(f'attributes - {event["attributes"]}')
    logger.info(f'content = {event["data"]}')
    logger.info(f'name - {name}')
```

which gives me the following log:

```
2022-07-27T20:30:28.705193Z
send-emailsu5jrky5cj5q [I 220727 20:30:28 main:32] attributes - {'Data': 'Production', 'Team': 'Arch'}
```

However, when I try to build a dictionary using the event['attributes'] I can't get any info. I am using the publish_message function shown above to build dictionaries using the attributes but the following

```
    if event.attributes:
        attributes = {}
        for key in event.attributes:
            value = event.attributes.get(key)
            attributes[key] = value
        u.send_template_email('test.html',
                              TO,
                              'test',
                              **attributes)
    else:
        u.send_template_email('test.html',
                              TO,
                              'test')
```

tells me that the term 'attributes' is undefined

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'attributes' is undefined
```

I also tried accessing the attributes in a similar fashion to accessing the data,

```
event['attributes'].items()
```

but received errors for that as well. I feel as though this must be possible but am not able to find any documentation helping me through this in Python.

Ideally others have had this issue and may be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: May I know where event.attributes came from?

Comment: Since event is a dictionary containing 'data' and 'attributes' I thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked some of my old code...

In a function that is triggered by a message from a pubsub topic, I had something like this:

```
# parse event attributes
if "attributes" in event and event["attributes"]:
    attr_dic = event["attributes"]    
    # handle attribute_1
    if "attribute_1" in attr_dic and attr_dic["attribute_1"]:
        # do something useful
```

and so on including handling incorrect cases and exceptions...

In a function, where the message is published to the pubsub topic, I had something like this:

```
PS.publish(
    PS_TOPIC, message_text_value.encode(),
    attribute_1=attribute_1_value,
    attribute_2=attribute_2_value)
```

Bear in mind that the names of the attributes and attribute values have some restrictions - see [Use Attributes](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#using-attributes)

Here is an example in the documentation: [Publish with custom attributes](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-custom-attributes#pubsub_publish_custom_attributes-python)

Here is how it is implemented: [GitHub - python-pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/client.py](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/b0f0e21cc339bdaa88835afbe3e3f7056bfdd309/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/client.py#L274)

Comment: This is helpful. I had continued working on this and stumbled on using similar syntax to parse the attributes. I had not thought of the idea of the 2nd if statement to get at the individual attributes. I am going to try that for another aspect of the work I need. I'll post my full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of al-dann answer above, as well as some additional work I did, I came up with the following:

```
if event['attributes']:
     attributes = event['attributes']
```

Once I did that, I can pass the attributes dictionary through the function I want it for using **attributes as an argument.